# Unity & Unity Remote 5 Android cannot USB test

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I started a project on Unity and I would like to test it on an Android device, but I am unable to do so. I researched every tutorial out there and couldn't find a solution that worked for me. Note: I have been using Android Studio and I am able to launch apps both through an emulator and a USB phone.

- I am pretty sure I correctly chose all the settings inside of Unity
  (followed every single tutorial I could find).
- Turned on developer mode on phone and tried multiple setting
  variations that I could find on the web.
- Made sure all the drivers are installed correctly (wouldn't be able
  to do stuff through Android Studio if I haven't).
- Uninstalled Unity and Unity Remote 5 multiple times.
- JDK and NDK seem to be working fine. Tried turning adb server on and
  off multiple times. Also I can see my device with the 'adb devices'
  command.
- I had some issues with MalwareBytes when installing Unity. I did try
  granting permissions to every Unity folder I could find, but I think
  MalwareBytes could be the culprit.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Is there another thing I could try? Any help is apreciated.

EDIT: I switched my VPN to a VPN that allows open source software and I also uninstalled Malwarebytes and replaced it with Avira. Did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I did not run in exact same issue, but working with Unity remote might be a little tricky.

It may require to launch Unity remote first before launching Unity itself. And I hope did not forget to ProjectSettings -> Editor -> Any Android Device option to be set. I'm talking about Window OS.

Comment: I am on Windows 10. I configured all of the settings in both Unity and on Android. I did try launching the app before the program, but failed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I also did everything was mentioned in tutorials and nothing helped.

Then I noticed that when I press 'Play' there's a message in the console "Set-up Android SDK path to make Android remote work in Unity". After I went to 'Edit'->'Preferencies' I unchecked the 'Android SDK Tools Installed with Unity(recommended)', then closed Unity, opened it again and checked the box again.

It worked for me, I hope it will help you too :)

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your phone to your PC, you may chose the file transfer option in your Android device, but charge mode worked for me, this is what I did:

1-Make sure that the "Any Android Device" option in Project Settings/Editor, is enabled and close unity.

2-Open the Unity remote app in the phone and connect it to the PC, in charge only mode.

3-Open Unity and run the game

This method worked for me, I hope it works for you too.